# How to do I resolve Power Automate Cloud Flow Error Status Code 302 HTTP

Tags: http, power-automate

I have a flow where the following is taking place

1. Query an SQL Database and retrieve a dataset with 21780 records
2. Parse the ResultSets.Table records over to JSON
3. Using HTTP connector perform POST to an Excel worksheet
   [image]
4. This has worked in the past but recently we went over 20K rows now the flow fails with a Redirect error.
   [image]
5. The raw outputs are below

   ```
   {
       "statusCode": 302,
       "headers": {
           "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
           "request-id": "8b125471-c9fd-4770-b2e4-",
           "client-request-id": "8b125471-c9fd-4770-b2e4-",
           "x-ms-ags-diagnostic": "{\"ServerInfo\":{\"DataCenter\":\"East US\",\"Slice\":\"E\",\"Ring\":\"4\",\"ScaleUnit\":\"001\",\"RoleInstance\":\"BY1PEPF00002543\"}}",
           "Cache-Control": "private",
           "Date": "Wed, 16 Aug 2023 23:41:41 GMT",
           "Location": "/error/error.html?aspxerrorpath=/x/_layouts/xlrestinternal.aspx",
           "Content-Length": "0"
       }
   }
   ```
6. If we update the SQL in step one with SELECT TOP 20000 the HTTP POST does not fail.
7. We tried Enabling Pagination. Set a Threshold value, Allow chunking with no success.
8. We also tried the `Apply to each` with an `Add a row into table` - which works but takes Hours to process the data; not to mention the cost we are incurring per execution.
   [image]

I suppose HTTP is the wrong connector to get this data over to an Excel document - What connector should we use to move such datasets over?

Comment: You can always manually page your data and load it in that way.  Use `skip` and `take` over your dataset and load 10,000 records at a time or something.  Make sense?  You'd need to just keep looping until the `skip`/`take` call didn't return any results.

Comment: Like this concept ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70670651/power-automate-flow-process-json-output-in-50-parallel-branches/70674184#70674184